whereIn query return exact those ids ... or nothing
I am trying to filter something in laravel eloquent and I am not sure how to do it.
I have this array: $companyIds = [1,2,3] 
The whereIn query bellow:
->where(function($query){
   $query->whereHas('companies', function($query) use($companyIds) {
      $query->whereIn('company_id', $companyIds)
   });
})

it returns the companies ... with the id 2 and 3.
WhereIn it returns something... if it has found at least one of the id in the array.
But I don't want like that... I want to return all the the companies with the mentioned id ... or nothing.
How can I do that?
Update
It seems to work like this:
foreach($companyIds as $id) {
   $query->whereHas('company', function($query) use($id) {
      $query->where('company_id', $id);
   });
}


whereIn() will match against any of the IDs provided, not all of them. You'll likely need to loop over your IDs and add a clause ->andWhereHas('companies', function ($query) use ($id) { $query->where('company_id', $id) }) (or similar) so that your query only returns results when every ID matches.

yes I get your point....I tried but andWhereHas it seems that is not defined.....it trows and error.

@calin24 your solution works but it will execute multiple queries for each company_id, havingRaw performs the check directly in the database

Ah sorry, I guess whereHas() acts like an and; for clarification there's a method ->where() and supporting ones ->andWhere() and ->orWhere(); figured there was one for whereHas(), but I guess not.

Your requirement is called "relational division." I added the tag, you can check other answers for that tag to study a variety of solutions.

whereIn checks if a record has at least one matching value from the array.
To return a record only when all specified companyIds exist you can do something like:
$query->whereHas('companies', function($query) use($companyIds) {
    $query->whereIn('company_id', $companyIds);
})
->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT companies.company_id) = ?', [$totalIds]);

It first checks for related companies that matches the array. Then havingRaw part makes sure that the number of distinct company_ids found equals the total count in your array. If any id is missing the record won't be included.
